# set a the capacity of a vector when collecting elements

Tags: rust, iterator, collect

I am working on a project where I need to repeatedly collect a known number of elements from a buffer into a vector, my current code is:

```rust
let mut info: Vec<i32> = buffer.trim().split(" ").collect()
```

However, as I know that I will receive 2 elements I would like to be able to set the capacity of the vector, something like:

```rust
let mut info: Vec<i32>::with_capacity(2) = buffer.trim().split(" ").collect()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the vector using `with_capacity()` and then use [`.extend()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend) to fill it from an iterator:

```
let mut info = Vec::with_capacity(2);
info.extend(buffer.trim().split(" "));
```